# Python CGI executable script downloads / shows script code

Tags: python, apache, cgi

A script I wrote long ago (getWords.py) used to be executable at my localhost (http://local.example.com/getWords.py?query-string)

My python script starts like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# chmod 755 getWords.py

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

import os, sys, time, cgi, cgitb, re
import json, hashlib, gzip, urllib, urllib2
cgitb.enable()
```

I have enabled ExecCGI

cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/username/Dropbox/vhosts/example/
    <Directory /home/username/Dropbox/vhosts/example>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.example.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.example.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But still the script force downloads (FireFox) or shows the script code (Chrome).

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 username username  4794 Jul 14 17:15 getWords.py`

Any idea what is wrong on my localhost ?

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb  4 2015 14:21:10
$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

On my host (Webfaction), its running at http://example.com/getWords.py?query-string

Comment: What happens when you do "$ ./getWord.py"? In any case, you shouldn't be able to access cgi-bin directory, regardless of filetype (handler). You should get 500 internal server error. Did you restart apache? (stupid Q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u add cgi handler in apache2

AddHandler cgi-script .py

https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/129-servers/757148-configuring-apache2-to-run-python-scripts

Comment: I don't understand how I missed this ! Thanks !