# Python CGI executable

Tags: python, apache, cgi, shebang

I am trying to implement CGI using python scripts. Whenever I open `127.0.0.1/hello`, the file gets downloaded instead of executing. Following is my `000-default.conf` file in `sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all 
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr-lib/cgi-bin/ 
    <Directory "/usr-lib/cgi-bin/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have python installed in

```
/home/musigma/anaconda3/bin
```

so I added the following as the shebang line to my python file

```
#!/home/musigma/anaconda3/bin python3
```

Following are the contents of my python file

```
#!/home/musigma/anaconda3/bin python3
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head><title>cgi script </title></head>")
print("<body>")
print('<p>I think it worked</p>')
for i in range(5):
    print("<h1>hello world</h1>")
print("</body>")
print("</head>")
```

I have placed the file in `/var/www`. I also ran the following line to make my python file an executable

```
sudo chmod 755 hello.py
```

But that still doesn't make my python script an executable. Instead of executing, the file gets downloaded. I am not sure how to make things work now. Any direction would be of great help. I have tried these links but they don't serve my purpose. I have already taken care of these things

[Python CGI executable script downloads / shows script code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446102/python-cgi-executable-script-downloads-shows-script-code)

I have been trying to figure this out since the last four-five hours and not sure what to do next. Any direction would be great.

PS: I am using ubuntu 16.04

apache version

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
```

Answer (score 3):

Only the directory `/usr-lib/cgi-bin/` is setup to allow executable CGI scripts. That is what the:

```
Options +ExecCGI
```

indicates.

So fix the `#!` line as pointed out already, then move the script to the directory `/usr-lib/cgi-bin/`.

Finally, use the URL path of `/cgi-bin/hello.py`.

For more information on setting up Apache for executable CGI scripts, see the Apache documentation at:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

Answer (score 0):

<s>What if you copy/symlink your file to `hello.cgi` and `hello.py`? Do then `127.0.0.1/hello.cgi` and `127.0.0.1/hello.py` produce the source code or the results of the execution?</s>

Try changing the first line of the script from:

```
#!/home/musigma/anaconda3/bin python3
```

to:

```
#!/home/musigma/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Also, I would have thought the path to your script was 127.0.0.1/hello.py (including the extension) by default.

Comment: can you explain a bit more (perhaps more so in layman terms)?